# Trying to change the node version but getting a "command not found error"

Tags: node.js

I am trying to upgrade my node version to a specific one so I can install a particular package but for some reason I am getting the error described in the title.

This is the cmd I am running:

`sudo n 14.20.0`

This is the error I am getting:

```
❯ sudo n 14.20.0
sudo: n: command not found
```

Some questions in SO suggest that might be related to the wrong path when we run:

`echo $PATH`

My path is showing a bunch of stuff, totally different from the reccomended that contains `/usr/local/sbin:`

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall/install `n`?

Comment: I have uninstalled node instead. Was expecting some work around rather than having to uninstall it and install again. Had to remove node through my shell etc otherwise could not remove it. Took me an hour to do so.